How to include graphics that could be surrounded by texts?
How to include graphics that could be surrounded by texts, as in the attached figure below?


see wrapfig package

... or the wrapstuff package

... or wrapfig2 ... or insbox together with capt-of or caption

To find them, use e.g. these search terms with your search engine: ctan wragfig
